# How to convert rds format data into shp format in R?

Tags: r, format, geospatial, shapefile, format-conversion

I have a map data whose format is `rds`. Now I want to use this data in another software which asks for `shp` format. How to convert `rds` format data into `shp` format in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is spatial object saved as a `R`-specific binary file of "Serialization Interface for Single Objects" type (see `?readRDS`) probably created at some point by `saveRDS()`, read your file with

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

x <- readRDS("path/to/the/rds_file.rds")
```

and then write it with:

```
rgdal::writeOGR(x, "path/to/destination", "filename", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Be sure **not** to put ".shp" at the end of your output filename.

Also be sure **not** to put a `/` at the end of the destination folder. Otherwise you might face the error

> Creation of output file failed

When the error

> Error: inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE

you might have forgotten the `x` as the first argument in the `writeOGR` function.

Comment: I successfully read the rds file but when I run the output code, there is the Error: inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE. Why?

Comment: you probably forgot to put the object (in my example `x`) into the `writeOGR` function. Also see my edit for the needed libraries.

Comment: I have installed two packages and put the x in my codes: '>library(rgdal) > library(sp) > a=readRDS('D:/data/chinamap/chinamap.rds') > rgdal::writeOGR(a, "D:/data/chinamap/", "china", driver = "ESRI Shapefile") ', but the error I said still appears. I am very confused.

Comment: if this doesn't work either, could you please add the output of `class(a)` and `typeof(a)`?

Comment: It doesn't work. The output of 'class(a)' is "data.frame", and the output of 'typeof(a)' is "list". Should I covert 'a' to another format?

Comment: The problem here is that you have spaitial data in a quite non spatial format. Therefore, you have to transform it first into spatial objects. Look into `?SpatialPointsDataFrame()`, `?SpatialLinesDataFrame()` or `?SpatialPolygonsDataFrame()`. Also have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29736844/3250126) to see how data frames can be converted into spatial data types. After you have `Spatial*DataFrame` object, the above solution will solve the rest.